# Activate virtualenv using alias

Tags: linux, bash, virtualenv

I can activate my python virtual environment from it's folder by entering `. bin/activate`.  I'd like to instead type a single word alias, such as `shazam`, from the home folder (or anywhere else) that activates the environment, changes to my master project folder, and lists my projects.

I tried creating an alias in .bashrc that pointed to an .sh file containing:

```
cd ~/path-to-virtual-environment
. bin/activate
cd ~/path-to-master-project-folder
ls -a
```

I was getting a permission denied error, so I ran `chmod u+x <script file>`.  The script now runs, but the VE does not activate and while the project folders are listed, the shell is not in the master project folder.  I would appreciate some guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: better yet, check out virtualenvwrapper, which makes it easier to manage virtualenvs.  https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Stack Overflow seemed like an appropriate venue since the question is about accessing my development environment and there are other answered SO questions about aliases, bash scripts, and accessing virtual environments (but not quite the same as what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate all your environments in `~/.virtualenvs` and install `virtualenvwrapper`. The command to activate an env is `workon shazam`. Command line completion is supported.

Now about your problem: you've tried to activate an environment in a shell script. That doesn't work because shell scripts run with another shell and env activation change their environments, not the current. I.e., the environment briefly activated but then at the end of the script the new shell exits and the environment deactivated.

There are two ways to overcome this.

1. Use aliases or shell functions instead of scripts — they are the only way to change the current shell's environment.
2. Run interactive shell at the end of your script (`exec $SHELL`). It inherits activated environment and gives you a command prompt. To deactivate simply exit the shell (`exit` or <kbd>[Ctrl]</kbd>+<kbd>[D]</kbd>.).

Comment: Using a shell function worked.  Thank you.  Adding 'exec $SHELL' did not activate the virtual environment-- probably user error.  I read up on virtualenvwrapper, and while I see the benefit, I don't envision having enough environments to warrant the additional complexity.  I'll revisit if my circumstances change.